# React Native app takes time for first launch

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-splash-screen

after using **[react-native-bootsplash](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash)** library, my app takes time to launch for the first time, and also after submitting the releasing version on the play store, I'm getting Pre-Launch report as: Your app took 22,761ms to launch for the first time.
I also noticed the same on the iOS too, here is my configuration:
My MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.qadaapp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.zoontek.rnbootsplash.RNBootSplash;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "Qadaapp";
  }

  /**
   * Returns the instance of the {@link ReactActivityDelegate}. There the RootView is created and
   * you can specify the renderer you wish to use - the new renderer (Fabric) or the old renderer
   * (Paper).
   */
  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new MainActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName());
  }

  public static class MainActivityDelegate extends ReactActivityDelegate {
    public MainActivityDelegate(ReactActivity activity, String mainComponentName) {
      super(activity, mainComponentName);
    }

    @Override
    protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
      ReactRootView reactRootView = new ReactRootView(getContext());
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
      reactRootView.setIsFabric(BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED);
      return reactRootView;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isConcurrentRootEnabled() {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable Concurrent Root (i.e. React 18).
      // More on this on https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html
      return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
    }
  }
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RNBootSplash.init(this);
    super.onCreate(null);
  }
}
```

My AndroidMainfest.file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.qadaapp">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:theme="@style/BootTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="qadaapp"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
      <meta-data
          android:name="preloaded_fonts"
          android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

My styles.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
    </style>
    <!-- BootTheme should inherit from Theme.SplashScreen -->
    <style name="BootTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/bootsplash_background</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/bootsplash_logo</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
    </style>
    
</resources>
```

Also I added this in my build.gradle file:
implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0"

My App.js:

```
    const unsubscribe = auth().onUserChanged(async usr => {
      if (!usr) {
        await _getSlideShows();
        setUser(null);
        return RNBootSplash.hide({fade: true});
      }
      if (usr?.uid) {
        let dbResult = await DB.collection('users').doc(usr?.uid).get();
        setUser(usr);
        if (dbResult?.exists) {
          let dbUser = dbResult.data();
          setUser(dbUser);
        }
        return RNBootSplash.hide({fade: true});
      }
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

When I was not using react-native-bootsplash, the app was working fast, however when I implemeneted the react-native-boot-splash library, my app's cold start time increased on both the platforms.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: I just ended up creating my own splash screen.

Comment: Did you try the latest react-native-bootsplash?

Comment: Haven't tried yet, I just created my own custom splash screen instead.